# How to use ViewBag as list in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

i need to use ViewBag as list inside another ViewBag and i am not understanding how should i do that.
here is my code:

```
 List<string> srclist = new List<string>();
            foreach(var item in candidateportfolio)
            {
                if(item.PortfolioID!=0 && item.ChandidateID!=0)
                {
                    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/ePortfolio/PortFolioContent/" + HobbyDetailID + "/Assignments/Exhb_" + item.PortfolioID + "_" + item.ChandidateID + ".jpg");
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
                    {
                        srclist.Add(filepath);
                    }
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Thumbnail = srclist;
```

candidateportfolio is an object of the class CandidatePortfolio.
I fetch the data in the class and check whether its fields are not empty.Then i add the filepath to the list and assign list to Viewbag

Then in View i use it like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Thumbnail as List<string>)
{   
<img src="@item" title="Learner:@ViewBag.FirstName" width="150px" height="150px" border="5" style="align:right;margin:10px"/> 
}
```

Now the problem is i also want to fetch ViewBag.FirstName as list.and i cannot run another list in this.Please tell me how should i do this.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a list containing both `FirstName` and the path to, say, a photo you can create a new class:

```
public class ThumbnailModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can add a `List<Thumbnail>` to the `ViewBag`.

But I would suggest just creating a strongly typed view with a relvant model containing a `List<Thumbnail>` property.

Comment: @Eben Roux hey thanx 4 answer and i know this will work...but the problem is filepath is not a member of any class.while FirstName does belong to a class.hence for time being i wantd to hav a way where i can add both this in a viewbag and then use it.Is there no other way apart from making a class?

Comment: @user1274646: if there is a one-to-one mapping between the file and the FirstName it will be easiest having the `ThumbnailModel` class that contains all the information and then a collection to iterate through.  You *could* go with, say, two arrays and use a normal for loop on one of the arrays and access the other by index but that is more effort than it's worth I think.

Answer (score 1):

user1274646,

your best bet here is to create a public class that contains both the exisiting thumbnail element plus an additional FirstName property. Here's how this might look:

```
public class CandidateItem{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string Filepath {get; set;} 
}
```

then, in your loop, create a new CandidateItem and add it to the list (i.e. List). Here's the amended code:

```
List<CandidateItem> srclist = new List<CandidateItem>();
foreach(var item in candidateportfolio)
{
    if(item.PortfolioID!=0 && item.ChandidateID!=0)
    {
        CandidateItem candItem = new CandidateItem();
        candItem.Filepath = Server.MapPath("~/ePortfolio/PortFolioContent/" + HobbyDetailID + "/Assignments/Exhb_" + item.PortfolioID + "_" + item.ChandidateID + ".jpg");
        candItem.FirstName = item.FirstName;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            srclist.Add(candItem);
        }
    }
}
ViewBag.Thumbnail = srclist;
```

then use it in the view as:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Thumbnail as List<CandidateItem>)
{   
    <img src="@item.Filepath" title="Learner:@item.FirstName" width="150px" height="150px"   border="5" style="align:right;margin:10px"/> 
}
```

Comment: hey thanx 4 such a nice answer and i know this will work...but the problem is filepath is not a member of any class.while FirstName does belong to a class.hence for time being i wantd to hav a way where i can add both this in a viewbag and then use it.Is there no other way apart from making a class?